# How to run a simple non web container in heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a single microservice to heroku. Effectively just a python script that does some work.
To run this locally it would be as simple as:

```
docker run -e user -e pass containername
```

I have read and read and I cannot figure out how to do the same in heroku which seems crazy because it should be so simple. Does anybody have any idea how to perform the equivalent action command in heroku?